# directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/default.d/app.conf:1 NGINX Config EC2

Tags: django, vue.js, nginx, amazon-ec2, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to configure my app to run on ec2 with some difficulty.
It's a multi container app built with docker-compose consisting of django, drf, channels, redis gunicorn, celery and nuxt for frontend.

I've an instance running and can SSH to the instance and install the relevant packages, docker nginx docker-compose etc.

What I can't do is edit my app.conf nginx file to use the public ip 33.455.234.23 (example ip)
To route the backend, rest and frontend.

I've created and app.conf nginx file which works fine local but when I try edit the nginx files
after install to configure my app to the public ip's I run into errors.
The error I have when writing my config is

```
2020/11/13 01:59:17 [emerg] 13935#0: "http" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/default.d/app.conf:3
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

This is my nginx config

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    client_max_body_size 100m;

    upstream asgiserver {
        server asgiserver:8000;
    }

    upstream nuxt {
        ip_hash;
        server nuxt:3000;
    }

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name localhost;

        location ~ /(api|admin|static)/ {
            proxy_pass http://asgiserver;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        }
   
        location /ws/ {
            proxy_pass   http://asgiserver;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            # proxy_redirect off;
        }
    
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://nuxt;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? What to I need to do in order to have my app running via reverse proxy on my ec2 public address?

Comment: Looks like you might be missing some closing `}`'s.

Comment: @ Red Cricket it's not a syntax issue. I've tried multiple configs now and same error on first block

Comment: Not sure I understand - are you trying to connect a public ip to a django app running on a specific port (i.e. port 8000)?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this configuration file isn't treated as the main configuration file by nginx but being included from the main main configuration file `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` which in turn already contains the `http` block with the `include` directive within, something like

```
include /default.d/*.conf;
```

Check this, if it is true, remove everything except upstream and server configuration blocks from the `/etc/nginx/default.d/app.conf` file. Move the `client_max_body_size` directive inside the `server` block.